# Gas water heater turn off the gas valve and water, but leave the thermostat at low level, will this cause some issue?

Tags: water, gas, heater

GAS water heater, I turn off the gas valve and water, but leave the thermostat at low level, didn’t turn it off. I will back the house in 10 days, Will this cause any issue?[image][image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Is there any electrical connection at all? If this is a "traditional" gas heater with pilot, the thermostat can't do anything at all without the pilot on, so no problem. If it has some sort of electronic ignition then it is a different situation. If you are not sure, post the model # and/or a picture of the controls and we can probably figure it out.

Comment: Surely all gas water heaters are designed to not be damaged if the gas is shut off without turning the thermostat to off first.

Comment: @manassehkarz I don’t know what’s version, but my heater is more than 10 years old and I didn’t see a ignition button next to the gas valve.

Comment: Not in the house, so not able to check the version. Another question is, I didn’t drain the water, so when the temperature is fall and under the setting of thermostat, will it continuously try to ignite the gas to burn the water? If yes, will it cause some problem?

Comment: @Jim Stewart I turn the gas valve off, but.didn't turn the ball valve on the gas pipeline off, is this fine? I saw somone said turn off the gas valve doesn’t mean completely turn off the gas.

Comment: In the US all gas appliances must have a valve in the line by the wall by the appliance. If you have turned off the gas valve on the line feeding the water heater, then you have completely turned off the gas to the water heater.  In addition, the water heater heater has an internal automatic shut-off valve that shuts if the pilot light goes out. In addition there is a shut-off valve on your gas meter, but as far as I know nobody shuts that off when going on vacation. If you shut that off, you *may be* legally required to get the gas company to turn it back on and do a leak test.

Comment: Where is this house? Did you leave the furnace on to keep the inside above freezing?

Comment: ok, which means I turned off the gas valve in above pic, that actually turn off the pilot, so the heater will automatically shut off the gas. But, is there any problem that I didn’t turn off the gas pipeline? And, I have left my furnace on at 51 f.

Comment: I think you can be confident that your gas is off. The water heater will not "try" to come on and it will not be leaking gas. *However* I am not an expert is the exact requirements for shutting off a water heater and *in the future* you should also turn off the valve in the supply line at the wall by the water heater. I am sure you have one. The reason is that you probably have a bendable supply line from the valve at the wall to the water heater and this bendable line is of thinner material and is not as secure as the heavy walled piping in the house's gas supply lines.

Comment: Thanks, @JimStewart, I already back the home, and I saw there has more cupric oxide on my pressure relief valve, I have open a new question from below link, do you have some idea about it? https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/153440/cupric-chloride-on-pressure-relief-valve-of-gas-water-heater

Comment: I saw there has something looks like ice inside of the tank, no ice outside of the tank. Is the tank frozen inside? @JimStewart

Comment: After you install the new TP relief valve turn the gas back on and see if the water heater works. Where did you look into the tank to see what looks like ice?

Comment: Is this tank in a heated space or is it in an unheated attic or other unheated space?

Comment: through the hole of TP relief. And, I just worried about if that's frozen or something wrong will cause the issue when I restart the water heater.

Comment: It's in the basement, and a little bit coder, but my other plumbing didn't freeze.

Comment: *Very, very* unlikely that the water in the tank froze. Fire it up and see what happens.

Comment: I have attached the pic, do you have some idea what's that? @JimStewart

Comment: I don't know what that is. If the hole is still open you could insert something to take a sample, but otherwise just fire up the water heater.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming everything's in good working order, then no problem. Turning off the gas killed the pilot and stopped the water heater from doing anything by the thermocouple.

However, based on your comments you may have bigger problems than a few wasted dollars from leaving the water heater running. **It seems** you shut the heat off to the house as well when you left and are worried about the water heater possibly freezing.

The water heater would be the last thing to freeze in being such a big and thick column of water. But yes, it could freeze after all of your other plumbing.

You must winterize properly to avoid damage to everything or just turn things down so they only maintain easier lower temperatures.

Comment: I have left my furnace on at 51 f.

Comment: So, freezing is not my concern, but leave the gas pipeline on is my concern (I did turn off the gas valve). But, I think my heater should be fine as the pilot is off.

Comment: I saw there has something looks like ice inside of the tank, no ice outside of the tank. Is the tank frozen inside?@lggy

Comment: Yep, you got some freezing, thank you very much for the pictures. It's nothing major, thankfully, and the ice could only block the flow out to the fixtures. Start the heater and give the ice an hour or so to melt, you'll be just fine.